# Copy e move construtores são chamados apenas na criação de um objeto?

Tags: c++, construtor

Os construtores *move* e *copy* só são chamados na criação de um objeto? se sim, depois da criação de um objeto, não é possível chamar nem explicitamente nem implicitamente o *move* ou *copy constructor* daquele objeto, né? A dúvida
surgiu daqui:

```
class Engine
{
public:
    Engine(int length) : m_size(length), m_ptr(new int[length])
    {

    }

    ~Engine()
    {
        delete[] m_ptr;
    }

    Engine(const Engine& e) : m_ptr(new int[e.m_size])
    {
        this->m_size = e.m_size;
        *this->m_ptr = *e.m_ptr;
    }

private:
    int* m_ptr;
    int  m_size;
};
```

Como podemos ver, quando o construtor é chamado, ele aloca espaço no *heap* pro `m_ptr`. Então, se de alguma forma o *copy constructor* fosse chamado após isso,
ele alocaria novamente memória no `m_ptr` e a memória previamente alocada seria vazada.

Eu já tenho quase certeza da resposta, mas como nunca vi nenhuma menção explicita sobre isso, deixo minha dúvida aqui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, eles não deixam de ser construtores. Depois que cria um objeto com ele se você chamar o construtor ele criará outro objeto, cada um independente do outro. Ou quase, o `m_ ptr` de cada um deles provavelmente apontará para o mesmo objeto, pelo menos certamente logo em seguida da cópia.

Na forma escrita tem uma chance razoável de ter vazamento de memória ou até ponteiro solto, mas nada a ver com o o construtor de cópia em si, só com a forma como o código dentro dele foi escrito, poderia ser em um outro método. Provavelmente este código não faz o que você espera e poderia ser melhor escrito, mas não sei qual a intenção.